# deploy Node.js Google Cloud Function with tsconfig.json extending parent tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, tsconfig

I used to deploy my Google Cloud Functions using the CI tools with `gcloud functions deploy testFunction --region europe-west1 --trigger-http --runtime nodejs16 --source ./testFunction --set-env-vars ...`
My directory structure was as follows (only showing necessary files):

```
.
├── testFunction
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

### My issue

Since about 2 days my Google Cloud Function has an error while building in Google Cloud Build. The problem is that the tsconfig.json from the root cannot be found. When I try to download the source that was uploaded to Google I can see that only the testFunction directory is being uploaded. Interestingly, it has been like this before as well and worked. So I assume that for some reason Google ignored the tsconfig.json in the past?

The file `testFunction/tsconfig.json` extends the parent `/tsconfig.json` from the root folder:

```json
// /testFunction/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "buildcache.tsbuildinfo"
  }
}
```

### Things I have tried/Temporary solution(s)

For now I have found two temporary solutions:

1. copy content of parent tsconfig.json and do not extend parent tsconfig.json
2. make an alias with `ln -s` and link the parent `tsconfig.json` as `parent.tsconfig.json` and extend that one instead.

Both solutions seem not very elegant and I wonder why this change has happened suddenly and if there is some better solution (like resolving the parent tsconfig.json during deploy/build or somehow including it in the build).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine the command you use to deploy your function while looking only at the relevant portion for your question:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy testFunction --source ./testFunction
```

This is telling the `gcloud` application to take the directory `./testFunction` and its contents and send them to Cloud Build. It's important to note that it will send **only** that directory and its contents; they become the **build context** for Cloud Build in the same way that there is a [Docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/).

I can't speak to why or how this appeared to work for you in the past. I am assuming that you are misunderstanding what happened in earlier deploys or have had a configuration change because what I'm describing for the build context with `gcloud functions deploy` has always been true.

Symlinks are going to be problematic as well because if you have a symlink in `./testFunction` that points to `../tsconfig.json` then when Cloud Build unpacks the build context it will be pointing to a file in the parent directory that doesn't exist. For example if it unpacks to `/app` it's going to look for `/tsconfig.json` inside the container where it was unpacked and not find it.

Understanding the build context is important when deploying Cloud Functions. It appears you have a monorepo and I would assume that you have more than this one function in it. Keep in mind that if you tell it to use `.` as the `--source` (or if you omit `--source`) then it's going to send the entire directory structure as the build context. This might not be what you want as you may have a lot of code there not necessary for building that one function.

What I recommend is having some kind of predeploy script that you run that prepares your function before calling `gcloud functions deploy`. For a monorepo that I run for Cloud Functions I have a script named `bin/deploy.sh` that accepts as an argument the path to a function, e.g., `bin/deploy.sh functions/testFunction`. It performs a number of tasks as a safeguard before deploy:

1. `cd functions/testFunction`
2. `yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --mode=skip-build` to check its packages
3. `yarn tsc` to ensure it builds
4. `yarn eslint .` to ensure it is valid
5. `yarn vitest run` to ensure the tests pass
6. `functions/testFunction/bin/deploy.sh` to run a customized `gcloud functions deploy` command for that individual function

With this I'm not relying on Cloud Build to run `tsc` for me; everything I ship through `gcloud functions deploy` is already built and ready to be deployed. If you still want Cloud Build to run `tsc` for you then you can add a step to the script that modifies `tsconfig.json` before deploy and then undoes the changes afterwards:

```bash
mv -f tsconfig.json tsconfig.testFunction.json && # Rename existing file
  cp -f ../tsconfig.json . &&                     # Copy parent file to this function
  gcloud functions deploy ... ;                   # Deploy the function and regardless of success or failure run the next command
  mv -f tsconfig.testFunction.json tsconfig.json  # Restore the original file
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I should have really looked into the gcloud functions changelog. Here is the change that broke my setup: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#April_11_2023

Before, google didn't build the project during deployment, so it used the function from my build folder. Adding "gcp-build": "" as a script in package.json fixed the issue for me!